Can the image of an everywhere rank zero map have dimension one?
Let $M \subset R^n$ be an $m$-dimensional properly embedded submanifold, and denote by $\pi_1$ the projection $M \rightarrow R$ of $M$ into its first coordinate. Assume I know that the rank of $\pi_1$ is zero everywhere in $M$.
Question: Can the image $\pi_1(M)$ be a non-degenerate subinterval of $R$?
I feel strongly that this cannot happen, but I cannot prove it. Perhaps I should be able to, but I can't. Certainly if I knew $M$ is connected it can't be the case, because I can then prove that $M$ must be an affine subspace, but barring that I am having difficulty.
As I say, the answer is probably an easy "no", I'd just like someone to confirm it. I'd also like to be able to prove it myself, so if there is a hint to be offered I'd gratefully receive it.
Edit: As Adayah and Matteo Gori pointed out, I had completely forgotten about the fact that $M$ has an at most countable number of connected components. I had used this fact just about a month ago, why it escaped me now I'll never know.
To Matteo Gori, thank you for the interesting alternative proof, it proves rigorously what I felt intuitively but couldn't prove myself. Also, the reason I said that I could prove $M$ was an affine subspace if I knew it was connected was because I happen to know that the tangent plane to $M$ at every point was the same fixed linear subspace. My comment was just meant as an aside (since I wasn't going to assume $M$ was connected anyway) but I simply neglected to add the crucial information that $T_p M$ was the same at all points. Of course, I still could be wrong, but I don't think so.

Your guess is true.
Hint: use the Sard's theorem and the fact that a manifold has a countable basis.
Another way: use your result for connected manifolds together with the fact that a manifold must have countably many connected components.

Thank You. Please see my comments in the edited post.

It's not true that if $M$ is connected than it's an affine subspace. It only works if $m=n-1$ and in that case it should actually happen that $M$ is an open connected subset of $\{0\}\times \mathbb R^{n-1}$ (open in the subspace topology), otherwise you could just consider any submanifold $M\subset \{0\}\times \mathbb R^{n-1}$ which doesn't have this form.
What is always true is that if $M$ is connected than $\pi_1(M)$ consists of $1$ point: if by contradiction $\pi_1(M)$ is an interval, by connection there is a $C^1$ curve $\gamma\colon I\rightarrow M$ such that the image of $\pi_1\circ \gamma$ is an interval, which means that there exists a $t\in\mathbb R$ such that $\pi_1\circ \gamma'(t)\neq 0$ (for example by Lagrange's theorem) and we know that $\gamma'(t)\in T_{\gamma(t)}M$ (absurd).
In general notice that the connected components of $M$ (let's call them $M_i$) are at most countable: in fact they are open in $M$ (since $M$ is locally connected) and $M$ is second countable (if it's not clear I'll edit the answer). Therefore $\pi_1(M)=\bigcup_i \pi_1(M_i)$ is at most countable and cannot be an interval.

Thank You. Please see my comments in the edited post.

@HerbF1978 as I've said in my answer, what you say is right only if $m=n-1$ (in your notation $m$ is the dimension of $M$). In fact the condition means that $T_xM\subset {0}\times \mathbb R^{n-1}$ for every $x\in M$ and this doesn't guarantee that $T_xM$ coincides with $ {0}\times \mathbb R^{n-1}$, unless $m=n-1$ (in which case it's true for dimensional reasons).

Sorry to bother you again, but I don't quite see it. If I simplify to $n=3$ and $m=1$ and consider $M \subset {0} \times R^2$ to be a straight line through the origin, wouldn't the rank of $\pi_1$ be zero at all points of $M$ and wouldn't $M$ be a linear (hence affine) subspace? I certainly believe you but perhaps if you can explain where I went wrong it will help me understand the situation better.

Your example works of course, but this doesn't prove that it has to happen. For example you can take $M={0}\times\mathbb S^1\subset {0}\times \mathbb R^2$ which has dimension $1$ like your example, but of course it isn't a subspace. What I was saying is just that it has to happen only if $m=n-1$, not that it can't happen if $m\neq  n-1$.

@Matteo Gori: OK, not to go off on a tangent (!) I guess I didn't make it clear that my ASSUMPTION was that the tangent space to $M$ was the same linear subspace at all points, clearly with ${0} \times S^1$ that is not the case. But, again, this was not the main point of my question, you (and Adayah) answered it and have my thanks.
